# Cut out image of UIView to reveal background tint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I currently have a main UIView that I have subclassed and set a custom background colour from a UIImage.

I also have a .png with a transparent background - lets call it myImage.png.

I want to be able to add the myImage.png to the main view so that I am able to animate the **non-transparent** portion of my UIImage. I assume that this could be achieved with the use of layers and image masking but I would really appreciate an example to get me started.

EDIT

To clarify, I am interested in knowing how I can use core graphics to cut out the myImage.png and reveal a tint colour. I can then animate this tint colour to give a flashing effect. I am able to animate the image without a problem,  so I need a solution to the problem of 'cutting out' the image and revealing a background tint that I my animate in and out.

I am using iOS6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with CAGradientLayer, CATransformLayer, CAReplicatorLayer.

As I understand your question you have a .png with transparent background and you want to animate the non-transparent part of this .png (myImage.png) you want to add myImage.png to your main view with an animation. Take a look of this apple documentation link of Core Animation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

It will help you with what you want

Comment: OK just read it. I will put a view behind my image using '[mainView insertSubView:backgroundView belowSubview:myImage];' then I will animate the layer of my backgroundView playing with the alpha.